# Escaping HTML in Ruby & adding to DOM with JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, escaping

I'm trying to dynamically add contents of a div using JS. Back end is Ruby on Rails. I am having a problem. Here's what is included in the view file:

`var product_sidebar_inner = "<%= CGI.escapeHTML(render(...some partial...)).gsub(/\r/," ").gsub(/\n/," ") %>";`

```
document.getElementById("left_sidebar_wrapper").innerHTML = unescape(product_sidebar_inner);
```

The above inserts html as text to div#left_sidebar_wrapper. Spent some time on this but still can't make this work. Any idea what am I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment to macarthy, I think you want [`CGI.escape`](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/CGI.html#M000319) (or `CGI.unescape`), that's what you use for URL encoding. You can also use [`URI.escape`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/classes/URI/Escape.html#M009395) (or `URI.unescape`) but you'll get tired of having to pass the `unsafe` regex all the time to get it to do what you want.

Also, on the JavaScript side, you should be using [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) or [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) as [`escape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Functions#escape_and_unescape_Functions) is deprecated because it has problems with non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 0):

THink you need to use raw

```
unescape(raw(product_sidebar_inner));
```

Comment: Well actually problem is on Ruby side. CGI.escapeHTML() escapes a test <h1> tag as '&lt;h1&gt;Test h1 -- escapeHTML&lt;/h1&gt;', while JS escape() produces '%3Ch1%3ETest%20h1%20--%20escapeHTML%3C/h1%3E'. Latter is the right one as it will be unescaped by JS nicely. So I need a function in RoR that produces result equivalent to JS escape()